# How can I show products using Load More Button instead of pagination. any idea?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I am working on E-commerce website. I want to show products on load more button click instead of pagination but it shows me previous products not next any reference or idea how can I do that. this is my code

```
$products = Product::with('category')->paginate(3);
  $(document).on('click','#loadmore',function(){
            $.get($ul.find("a[rel='next']").attr("href"), function(response) {
              console.log($(response).find("#productData").html());
              
              var data =  $(response).find("#productData").html();
              $posts.append(data);
            
          });
      });
```

Comment: If `response` is just a selector, and it matches a selector already on the page, then all you're doing is selecting something already on the page and duplicating it. You'll need to leverage Laravel for pagination or create a document fragment that you append `response` to and then grab your data from the fragment before appending to the page.

Comment: what does  `console.log($(response).find("#productData").html());` log? what does `console.log(response)` log?

Answer (score 1):

Load more is nothing but pqgination, the only difference is that you paginate on the click of load more button. You can use the next link in the `$products->nextPageUrl()` which laravel provides to load the next page (rmember to replace the href on the load more anchor after each call). For more info on laravel pagibation, look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Comment: But It removes the previous products

Comment: I just want on click of load More button 12 new products display after above products

Comment: where is `$posts` defined? Rather what exactly is it?